# Multiple ports within one function

Tags: python

```
import socket



def port_watcher(port):

    UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
    UDP_PORT = port

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

    while True:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
        print("received message:", data)


port_watcher(44134)
port_watcher(44135)
```

I want my function to continuously give me results from both ports but it is only printing out results from one at a time.

Comment: Look into threading if you wish to monitor both ports in this fashion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use threading, as mentioned by Robert Kearns:

```
import threading
import socket


def port_watcher(port):

    UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
    UDP_PORT = port

    print("Binding port: %s" % port)
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

    while True:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
        print("received message:", data)


threads = list()
for port in (44134, 44135):
    x = threading.Thread(target=port_watcher, args=(port,))
    threads.append(x)
    x.start()
```

Output:

```
Binding port: 44134
Binding port: 44135
```

Answer (score 1):

While threading does work, you can still check both ports in one run of the while loops using a list of ports:

```
import socket

class Port(object):
    def __init__(self, UDP_IP, UDP_PORT):
        self.UDP_IP = UDP_IP
        self.UDP_PORT = UDP_PORT

def port_watcher(ports):
    port_list = []

    #Connect each port
    for port in ports:
        index = len(port_list)
        port_list.append(Port("127.0.0.1", port))

        print("Binding port: %s" % port_list[index].UDP_PORT)
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        sock.bind((port_list[index].UDP_IP, port_list[index].UDP_PORT))

    while True:
        #Check each port
        for port in port_list:
            data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
            print("received message for port " + port.UDP_PORT  + ":" + data)


port_watcher([4134, 4135]) #You can put as many ports as you want as list elements
```